# how to merge separate date and time variable into one datetime format XSLT

Tags: xml, datetime, xslt, xslt-1.0

I need to merge separate date and time into one datetime format against XSLT. I am very newbie to XSLT. I have been googling around and tried my best. I couldn't find a solution. Hope you can help me with that. Thanks!

**Original xml file:**

```
 <ns0:TransactionRequests xmlns:ns0="http://tst.co.za/sa/co/cib/servicesV1">
    <CorporatePayments>
      <TransactionDate>20140926</TransactionDate> 
       <TransactionTime>001502</TransactionTime> 
    </CorporatePayments> 
</ns0:TransactionRequests>
```

**XSLT:**

```
 <xsl:template match="CorporatePayments" >
  <Transactions>
   <Transaction bankDate="{TransactionDate+TransactionTime}">
   </Transaction>
   <Transactions>
 </xsl:template>
```

**Expected Result in xml format:**

```
 <Transactions>
   <Transactions>
     <Transaction bankDate="2014-09-26T00:15:02"  />
 </Transactions>
</Transactions>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the following XSLT:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns0="http://tst.co.za/sa/co/cib/servicesV1" exclude-result-prefixes="ns0">
<xsl:output indent="yes" method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" />
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>
<xsl:template match="/ns0:TransactionRequests/CorporatePayments" >
    <Transactions>
        <Transactions>
            <xsl:variable name="D" select='TransactionDate'/>
            <xsl:variable name="T" select='TransactionTime'/>
            <Transactions bankDate="{concat(substring($D,1,4), '-',substring($D,5,2),'-',substring($D,7,2),'T',substring($T,1,2),':',substring($T,3,2),':',substring($T,5,2))}"/>
        </Transactions>
    </Transactions>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```